# How to fetch doctype eg: address or tax rule

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I want to fetch the doctype. How do I do this? I want to add a separate column which will give doctype such as sales order, purchase order etc. The first line gives me error what query should be fired. Please help I am new to ERP Next.

```
SELECT
    AD.ref_doctype AS “Doctype:Link/User:120”,
    AD.name AS “Doc#:Link/Doctype:120”,
    AD.owner AS “Created By:Link/User:120”,
    AD.modified AS “Modified On:Date:120”
FROM tabAddress AS AD

WHERE
    DATEDIFF(now(),AD.modified) BETWEEN 1 AND 30

UNION ALL

SELECT
    TR.name AS “Doc#:Link/Doctype:120”,
    TR.owner AS “Created By:Link/User:120”,
    TR.modified AS “Modified On:Date:120”
FROM tabTax Rule AS TR
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(now(),TR.modified) BETWEEN 1 AND 30

UNION ALL

SELECT
    IT.name AS “Doc#:Link/Doctype:120”,
    IT.owner AS “Created By:Link/User:120”,
    IT.modified AS “Modified On:Date:120”
FROM tabItem AS IT
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(now(),IT.modified) BETWEEN 1 AND 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't completely clear to me what you mean by docType field.

Are you wanting a result like this?

```
Doctype:Link/User:120|Doc#:Link/Doctype:120|Created By:Link/User:120|Modified On:Date:120|
---------------------|---------------------|------------------------|--------------------|
Email Account        |Jobs                 |Administrator           | 2019-12-04 06:07:55|
Email Account        |Notifications        |Administrator           | 2019-12-01 05:25:53|
Email Account        |Replies              |Administrator           | 2019-12-01 05:25:53|
Email Account        |Sales                |Administrator           | 2019-12-04 06:07:55|
Email Account        |Support              |Administrator           | 2019-12-04 06:07:55|
```

Here's the select :

```sql
set @docType = "Email Account";
SELECT
    @tabDocType  AS `Doctype:Link/User:120`,
    AD.name AS `Doc#:Link/Doctype:120`,
    AD.owner AS `Created By:Link/User:120`,
    AD.modified AS `Modified On:Date:120`
FROM `tabEmail Account` AS AD
```

Note the backticks on the field aliases! All these have different meanings in SQL:

```
"
'
`
```

The last one, backtick, is used to refer to database entities.  You were trying to use `“Doctype:Link/User:120”` with double quotes, which declare plain text.  Using backtick converts the alias into a db entity which can be referred to from elsewhere.

MariaDb doesn't allow the use of variables as table names directly, but you can do it using prepared statements, like this:

```sql
set @docType = "Email Account";
set @tabDocType = CONCAT('tab', @docType);
SET @sql_text = concat('

SELECT 
    "', @docType, '"  AS `Doctype:Link/User:120`
  , AD.name AS `Doc#:Link/Doctype:120`
  , AD.owner AS `Created By:Link/User:120`
  , AD.modified AS `Modified On:Date:120`
FROM `', @tabDocType, '` as AD;

');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The table name is now also specified by a variable, created from concatenation of  'tab' with the `docType` declared before.

You get the same result as above but -- you avoid accidentally changing the table name in one place but not in the other when editing some time in the future.

Comment: This is what I wanted.


SELECT
  
"Address" AS "Doctype:Link/Doctype:120",
  
AD.name AS "Doc#:Link/Address:120",
  
AD.owner AS "Created By:Link/User:120",
  
AD.modified AS "Modified On:Date:120"
 
FROM tabAddress AS AD
 
WHERE

DATEDIFF(now(),AD.modified) = 1

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

to fetch doctype name you have to give the linked doctype name, For example,
select 
  IT.name as "IT No:Link/IT:120"

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But IT.name AS “Doc#:Link/Doctype:120” is giving me the IT.name(Item Name) the same output line which you told. I want a separate column which should mention Doctype as Item(IT),Address(AD) and Tax Rule(TR).

Comment: I want to fetch doctype field and not doctype name.